# Avoid using when condition for each task, while including an Ansible validation role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have the following `roles` structure:

```bash
$ tree roles
roles
├── user
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yaml
└── validation
    └── tasks
        └── main.yaml
```

My goal is to include the `validation` role into multiple roles and avoid using a `when` condition, into every task.

`validation/tasks/main.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Test model
  ansible.builtin.command: grep 'Debian' /proc/device-tree/model
  changed_when: false
  register: model

- name: Set fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    debian: true
  when: model.rc == 0
```

`user/tasks/main.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Perform validation
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: validation

- name: Get user info
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: user
    state: present
  register: user_info
  when: debian | default(false)
```

`playbook.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Deployment
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: user
```

When I run the playbook, everything works as expected. My goal is to avoid adding inside each task that `when` condition.

Is there a way to create a handler which will perform automatically a validation for each role task? The above example is very limited, the actual playbook contains many roles, with each task being required to be validated.

My end-result should be:

```yaml
  roles:
    - role: user
    - role: os
    - role: reset
    ...
```

Where each role task would automatically perform a validation during execution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the question you say: *"each role task would automatically perform a validation during execution"* and in the comment to my answer you say: *"there are many additional validation steps, needed to be contained into validation role"*. Putting it together opens a question: Do you want to automatically run a *validation* role during the execution of each role task?

Comment: Yes, I always run a validation role during the execution of each role task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by including the `validation` role into `meta`.

`user/meta/main.yaml`:

```yaml
---
dependencies:
  - role: validation
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using when condition in role modifying playbook.yaml like this using any variable you may need in when condition:

```
---
- name: Deployment
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: user
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

For more information check ansible documentation here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-with-roles

Also if you need this, in playbook.yaml you may set any variables needed for a role to run.

Comment: You cannot execute a condition if the role is included. My goal is to emulate the `when` condition with some sort of handler, which will perform the validation on any tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The *validation* is not needed. Use Ansible variable *ansible_os_family* instead. See [*gather_facts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-gather-facts-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_os_family
```

gives

```yaml
  ansible_os_family: Debian
```

You want to perform a role for multiple operating systems (or families of OS). In this case, you have to decide where to place the conditions.

a) If you want to use the *`role`* keyword you have to place the conditions inside the roles because the facts will be gathered after the roles are loaded. In other words, the variable *ansible_os_family* won't be available before a role is loaded.

```yaml
  roles:
    - role: user
    - role: os
    - role: reset
```

For example, create role *`user`*

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
└── user
    └── tasks
        ├── Debian.yml
        ├── FreeBSD.yml
        └── main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/user/tasks/main.yml 
- include_tasks: "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
shell> cat roles/user/tasks/Debian.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Manage users for Debian
shell> cat roles/user/tasks/FreeBSD.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Manage users for FreeBSD
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost,test_11
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - user
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost,test_11] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
ok: [test_11]

TASK [user : include_tasks] **********************************************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-178/roles/user/tasks/Debian.yml for localhost
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-178/roles/user/tasks/FreeBSD.yml for test_11

TASK [user : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Manage users for Debian

TASK [user : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: Manage users for FreeBSD

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_11: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

b) If you want to use the module *`include_role`* the situation is more flexible. For example, you can create roles for particular OS families

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
├── user_Debian
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── user_default
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── user_FreeBSD
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── user_RedHat
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/user_Debian/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "Manage users for {{ ansible_os_family }}"
```

Declare the variables, for example in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/role_user_family.yml
roles_user_family:
  Debian: user_Debian
  FreeBSD: user_FreeBSD
  RedHat: user_RedHat
  default: user_default

role_user_family: "{{ roles_user_family[ansible_os_family]|
                      default(roles_user_family.default) }}"
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost,test_11
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ role_user_family }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost,test_11] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
ok: [test_11]

TASK [include_role : {{ role_user_family }}] *************************************************

TASK [user_Debian : debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Manage users for Debian

TASK [user_FreeBSD : debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: Manage users for FreeBSD

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_11: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Notes:

- See available [platforms](https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v1/platforms/)
- See other distribution facts, for example

```yaml
shell> ansible test_host -m setup | grep ansible_distr
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "Debian",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "20",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "focal",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "20.04",
```

Comment: Vladimir, that validation is just an example, there are many additional validation steps, needed to be contained into validation role.

Comment: Floren, in the above framework, you can run any role conditionally including a *validation* role. In the context of your question, the statement *"The validation is not needed"* means that the content of this role is not needed, i.e. use the variable *ansible_os_family* instead of running *"command: grep 'Debian' /proc/device-tree/model"* and setting facts.

Comment: Vladimir, I understand well your concept. In my specific case, the validation role prevents the playbook execution, for a very specific set of conditions, which for convenience I want them managed inside the validation role. In other words, if the validation fails, the playbook with its many roles is not executed.

As a side note, I'm currently looking at the `meta/main.yaml` with `dependencies` block.

Comment: OK. [edit] your question and make it [mre]. Answer the comments below your question first. There is no point in commenting on an answer until it is clear what you want.